# Query always the same with Sunspot/Solr on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I have a problem with sunspot. When i do a SOLR request i have always the same query.

`SOLR Request (3.7ms)  [ path=select parameters={fq: ["type:Tag"], start: 0, rows: 30, q: "*:*"} ]`

No matter what I type in the search field , it's always the same query

Here my code :

**tag.rb**

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :pictogram
    searchable do
        text :name
    end
end
```

**searchs_controller.rb**

```
class SearchsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        if params[:search]
            pictograms = Array.new
            @term = params[:query]
            search = Tag.search do
                fulltext @term
            end


            index = 0
            search.results.each do |t|
                if !pictograms.include? t.pictogram
                    pictograms[index] = t.pictogram
                    index = index + 1
                end
            end

            @results = pictograms.group_by { |p| p.category }
            @search_mode = true
        end
    end
end
```

**index.html**

```
<%= form_tag result_search_path do %>
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
        <%= search_field_tag :term,"#{@term}", class: 'form-control' %>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <%= submit_tag "Search", :class => 'btn btn-primary btn' %>
        </span>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the params you are using for search are not correct.

```
<%= search_field_tag :term,"#{@term}", class: 'form-control' %>
```

means that the params that you are passing back to the controller is [:term],

so the code should be something like:

```
if params[:term].present?
            pictograms = Array.new
            @term = params[:term]
            search = Tag.search do
                fulltext params[:term]
            end
```

and not params[:search] and params[:query] like you have tried.